# Pegar informações AIMS e-Crew schedule?

Tags: android, scheduler

Tem uns app e site que mostram a agenda dos comissarios de bordo. Queria saber como esses sites pegam essas informações? É através de api?

Exemplos:
Site
https://aims.etihad.ae/wtouch/wtouch.exe/index

App
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chw.DroidAIMS&hl=pt_BR

Estou querendo fazer um app como TCC, mas não encontro informações sobre isso na net.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

No quesito site e aplicação mobile, para obter informações específicas ou supostamente sigilosas é necessário ter acesso a uma API.

Nos cassos desses sites/app comentados por você, eles usam uma API que obtêm os dados necessários para montar planilhas, agendas e relatórios para o usúario final.

Se a sua intenção é criar um aplicativo para obter dados de uma empresa ou companhia, você precisa saber se ela disponibiliza uma API ou as informações que você precisa.

Exemplos mais comuns são aplicações que usam dados do Facebook, Instagram, Twitter e entre outras.

Se tiver dúvidas sobre como começar a desenvolver visite o site de desenvolvedor do Google.

https://developers.google.com/android/